# How can I change cursor while scrolling a div in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

I have scroll on a div. And I want to change my cursor sign, when user scroll that div. And for other page scrolls, that should remain the default one.

How can I do that in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Did you find a solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('div:hover').css({'cursor':'whatever'});
```

OR

```
$('div').scroll(function() {
    $(this).css({'cursor':'whatever'});
});
```

CSS

```
div:hover { cursor: whatever }
```

See the cursor options here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: But it change the pointer when I mouse over to that element. I want only to change the cursor when user is scrolling that element. The idea what I am getting is, I have to change the cursor while scrolling to that element. Am I right?

Comment: See the second jQuery example. Update your selectors with a more specific id or class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MyDivsID").on('scroll', function() {
   $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer'); //or whatever cursor you'd like
});
```